# Android application download wordpress content

Tags: php, android, wordpress

I have an android application that need to download (via webservice - php ) some books from a wordpress website.

Those books are structured like this : Book Name -> Category 1 -> Subcategory 1 -> text

All information is stored in wp_posts and all realtions are made with wp_postmeta.

I try to begin from "top-to-bottom" starting with "Book Name" like this :

```
$args = array(
 'posts_per_page' => 8,
 'orderby' => 'rand',
 'post_type' => 'biblie',
 'post_status' => 'publish'
);
  $show_albums = get_posts( $args ));
```

and then with wp_query() using post_type, meta_key,meta_value

But any step i take with this method it gets more and more puzzling

So .... is there a way to have all the information using one interogation? I want to interogate wp by book name and somehow have all the information resulting in one arrayor it is to much from wordpress ?

Hope you understand my english !
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins that give you a restful api out of the box which could do what you want. A quick search gave me these:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API